# Class variables leaking when defined from a module?

Tags: ruby

Consider that I have a module `XYZ`. When included in a class, it extends the base class and adds a *class variable* `@@foo` inside it. It also extends the class with the methods to do some `get` and `set`.

```
module XYZ
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      @@foo ||= []
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      class_variable_get("@@foo")
    end

    def foo=(arg)
      class_variable_set("@@foo", arg)
    end

    def dynamic_set(*args)
      foo += args # This doesn't work
    end

    def dynamic_set_2(*args)
      class_variable_set("@@foo", class_variable_get("@@foo") + args)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, consider the usage:

```
class A
  include XYZ
end
A.foo #=> []
A.class_variable_get("@@foo") #=> []
A.dynamic_set 1, 2 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
A.dynamic_set_2 1, 2 #=> [1,2]
A.foo #=> [1,2]
A.class_variable_get("@@foo") #=> [1,2]
```

The snippet makes sense and gets the work done, but I'm not able to figure out why `A.dynamic_set 1, 2` didn't work.

Coming to the main part of the question - If I define a new `class B` as:

```
class B
  include XYZ
end
B.foo #=> [1,2] => Why? How did B.foo get these values?
B.class_variable_get("@@foo") #=> [1,2] => Why?
B.dynamic_set_2 3, 4
B.foo #=> [1,2,3,4]
A.foo #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Why are `B` and `A` sharing the same class variable when `@@foo` is defined on the class level (with `class_eval`)?

I understand about implications of using class variable and class instance variables. Just trying to figure out why this doesn't work as intended, to clear some concepts :)

Comment: That is how class variables work.

Comment: @sawa: In class hierarchies, yes. But why here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm not able to figure out why A.dynamic_set 1, 2 didn't work.

Use an explicit receiver when calling setters:

```
def dynamic_set(*args)
  foo += args # This doesn't work
  self.foo += args # This DOES work
end
```

> Coming to the main part of the question

**TL;DR:** Don’t use class variables. Use instance variables at class level.

```
module XYZ 
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      @foo ||= []
    end 
  end 

  module ClassMethods
    def foo 
      instance_variable_get("@foo")
    end 

    def foo=(arg)
      instance_variable_set("@foo", arg)
    end 

    def dynamic_set(*args)
      self.foo += args # This doesn't work
    end 

    def dynamic_set_2(*args)
      class_variable_set("@foo", instance_variable_get("@foo") + args)
    end 
  end 
end
```

---

It’s worth to mention it in the answer.

```
module XYZ
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval { @@foo ||= [] }
  end
end
```

The code above pollutes the `XYZ` class variables with `@@foo` **because `@@foo` is hoisted in `XYZ` module**.

`base.class_variable_set(:@@foo, [])` instead would not pollute `XYZ`.

Comment: But _why_ class variable behaves that way? :)

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa - I understand about class instance variables and why it should be used. In this case, I am surprised and wondering why class variables are behaving this way? class variables should only be accessible in base class and it's child classes.

Comment: “class variables should only be accessible in base class and it's child classes”—plain wrong. There are many resources (tons of them) on why it behaves how it behaves. This is done intentionally by Matz and I would not share my own opinion on why nice persons sometimes take wrong decisions.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I mean, there's no class hierarchy here. By design, class variables are visible in a class and its descendants. Here it seems to travel up the ancestors chain and then _down_.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev class hierarchy here starts with `XYZ.singleton_class`. Are you trolling?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Inclusion of a module is internally handled as class hierarchy.

Comment: @mudasobwa No, not trolling, just not enough coffee. Ancestors chain, yes. _But_ the var is set with class_eval. Hence, it's the base that should own it, not the module. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @mudasobwa: it _does_ only work downwards, tho: https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/89a48dbb706267221669f29d7ada78bf

Comment: Thanks, I just did `XYZ.class_variables` and it showed `@@foo`. Weird. I didn't expect that via `class_eval` and so much complications with class variables

Comment: @kiddorails: one more reason to avoid them :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It does not contradict with the gist you have pasted. When a module is included into a class, the module becomes the parent of the class. (With `prepend`, the module becomes a child of the class, and I am not sure what happens with it.)

Comment: @sawa the same: `module M; end; class C; prepend M; end; C.ancestors.first #⇒ M`.

Comment: @sawa: but here the var is not defined in the module. It's defined on the base directly (supposedly).

Comment: ah I think I got it, hold on :)

Comment: Nope, not seeing it. Guys, would you bear with my stupidity for a minute and explain why one class_eval is different from the other. https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/89a48dbb706267221669f29d7ada78bf

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Exactly! Getting that in `XYZ.class_variables` with `class_eval` is a mystery. I'm not sure if it's because of some  behavior of `class_eval` or just yet another issue with class variables as @sawa is pointing to.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev lol, it’s hoisting of `@@foo` inside `XYZ.included`. `base.class_variable_set(:@@foo, [])` would not pollute `XYZ`.

Comment: oh. hoisting in module (from method) since class_eval wouldn't create scope-gate ?

Comment: Class variables are obviously not affected by scope gates. Otherwise you’ll get issues accessing them from methods.

Comment: Thanks. This explains a lot :)